# json data custom http request

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

So far all I've been working with is receiving data from an restAPI using json in objective-c (using SBJson classes).  I am now attempting to send post data but I have no experience with it.  The raw body looks something like the following:

```
  //http://www.myapi.com/api/user=123
  "Username": "foo",
  "Title": null,
  "FirstName": "Nick",
  "MiddleInitial": null,
  "LastName": "Foos",
  "Suffix": null,
  "Gender": "M",
  "Survey": {
         "Height": "4'.1\"",
         "Weight": 100,
               }
```

What would be the best way this type of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have the post data in a string, called `myJSONString`.  (Getting from Objective-C collections to the json is straight-forward too.  Looks like @Joel answered that).

```
// build the request
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://www.mywebservice.com/user"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

// build the request body
NSData *postData = [myJSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// run the request
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if (!error) {
                               // yay
                           } else {
                               // log the error
                           }
                       }];
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I've got a question.  I am also having to send a unique key as a customer header.  How would I go about sending that as well?

Comment: Sure.  [request setValue:@"value" forHTTPHeaderField:@"key"];

Answer (score 1):

You want a dictionary with entries for each key above, then convert the dictionary to a JSON string. Note that the Survey key is a dictionary itself. Something like this.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictJson= [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dictJson setObject:@"foo" forKey:@"Username"];
...
[dictJson setObject:dictSurvey forKey:@"Survey"];

//convert the dictinary to a JSON string
NSError *error = nil;
SBJsonWriter *jsonWriter = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];
NSString *result = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:dictJson error:&error];
[jsonWriter release];
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I had no idea how to approach the surveys dict.  This will def work.